# python3 aiohttp server can't get real ip behind nginx

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, aiohttp

I am using aiohttp (http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) behind nginx with https:

I try to get IP in aiohttp middleware:

```
peername = request.transport.get_extra_info('peername')
host, port, = (peername if peername is not None else ('',''))
```

I expect real IP, but it always return 127.0.0.1
What's the reason of this problem and how to fix it?

my nginx conf:

```
upstream site_python {
        ip_hash;
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        server 127.0.0.1:8082;
        server 127.0.0.1:8083;
    }



server {
    listen      11.111.11.111:80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}



server {


    listen      11.111.11.111:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /home/site/ssl/www_site_ru.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/site/ssl/561457962.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


    server_name www.example.com; 
#    rewrite     ^ http://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;



  if ($host != 'www.example.com') {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
  }



    location / {
        proxy_pass http://site_python$request_uri;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host www.example.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    

    }

}
```

I also try to find it in extra but there is also no real IP in it.

```
print(request.transport._extra)

{'sockname': ('127.0.0.1', 8080), 'socket': <socket.socket fd=32, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=6, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 8080), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 48154)>, 'peername': ('127.0.0.1', 48154)}
```

Answer (score 5):

I solve it with

```
host = request.headers.get('X-FORWARDED-FOR',None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `peername` is always the IP of the *directly connected* machine. The IP of the original client is only accessible via HTTP headers, in this case set in the nginx configuration via `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`.

If you would like to get the original client IP, try

```
host = request.remote
```

See [web_request.py](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/web_request.py#L303)

Comment: it does not work "'Request' object has no attribute 'remote'"

Comment: Sorry, it's a property, not a method. I fixed the answer!

Comment: `request.remote` property is added to master branch but not released yet.

Comment: `request.remote` is a property that also uses `transport.get_extra_info('peername')` which ultimately returns `socket.getpeername()` so it's pretty much useless in the context of the question. You would need something like `django-ipware` which is able to determine the correct remote IP from the request headers.